# Show that the sequence $(u_n(t))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $t^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

For my homework assignment, I had to use Picard iteration to find a sequence $\{u_n(t)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to estimate a solution for the Initial Value Problem $$u'(t) = \frac{2u(t)}{t}$$
The sequence I got (and proved to be correct) is:
$$u_n(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2^i}{i!}\ln^i|t|$$
What is left for me to do is take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since the ODE is seperabel, I know the $u_n(t) \rightarrow t^2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, I have failed to prove this.

I had ideas using the comparison and/or integral tests but then I have difficulties with finding the correct bounds to use the sandwhich principle. Can anybody give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u_n(t)$ is just the $n-$th partial sum of the series $\sum \frac {x^{i}} {i!}$ where $x =2\ln |t|$. Hence it converges to to $e^{2\ln |t|}=t^{2}$.

Comment: I didn't have that insight to be able to see that. Thank you :D